# Как используя jvectormap отобразить карту только одного региона?

Tags: map

Доброе.
Используя jVectorMap хочу вывести карту только одного региона России. Для этого скачал 'ru_merc'. Из файла удалил все регионы кроме одного. Удалил раздел insets. Оставшийся регион показывает, но показывает его в том месте где он находится на карте России т.е. маленьким белым пятнышком.
Как сделать так чтобы карту показывало на все выделенное место? Игрался с параметрами "height" и "width" карты - не помогает.